# ArrayList of String becomes doubled while adding inside for loop

Tags: java, json

I am looping through a JSONArray. `names` and `amount` are `ArrayList <String>`

```
JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i) {
  JSONObject rec = data.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = rec.getString("name");
  names.add(i, name);
  String amount_v = rec.getString("amount");
  amount.add(i, amount_v);
  Log.v(logtag, i + " - " + names.size());
}
Log.v(logtag, "final - " + names.size());
```

For every  value of i, names.size() is twice that of i even though I am adding only one element inside the loop. data has 5 records with name and amount as two columns.
But after the loop, names contain all 10 values (5 names and 5 amounts). But actually, only 5 names should have been added to names list.

What I see in the log..

```
0 - 2
1 - 4
2 - 6
3 - 8
4 - 10
final - 10
```

Why does it add the value of `amount_v` into the names list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the two references called `amount` and `names` refer to the same ArrayList instance.

Comment: Oops. Thats right. While initializing them, I did like this, `names = amount = new ArrayList<String>();` Thank you :)